# At what modifiers are the attacks from the Two-Weapon Fighting feats made?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, combat

I am aware that this may seem like a basic question or may have a duplicate (although I checked for both, and if this case I would happily remove the question) but I am curious about how many attacks and at what BAB those attacks are made if a character has if they go down the Two Weapon Fighting feat tree. Below are the feat descriptions of *Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting* and *Greater Two-Weapon Fighting*.

> **Improved Two-Weapon Fighting:** In addition to the standard single extra attack you get with an off-hand weapon, you get a second attack with it, albeit at a - 5 penalty (see Table 8-10, page 160).
>
> **Greater Two-Weapon Fighting:** You get a third attack with your off-hand weapon, albeit at a -10 penalty.

The Player's Handbook is fairly clear that if the off-hand weapon is light then the penalties are -2/-2.

---

**So...**

Assuming a 11 level fighter with BAB of +11/+6/+1, a strength bonus of +1(for the sake of simplicity), wielding a shortsword(1d6) in his mainhand and a kukri(1d4) in the off-hand.

How many and can he have and at what BAB if he has TWF, and ITWF? What weapons are used for each attack?

How many and can he have and at what BAB if he only has TWF, ITWF and GTWF? What weapons are used for each attack?

Comment: I’m *pretty sure* the linked question covers everything this one does; if not, please edit this one to focus on things you still need help with, and we can re-open it.

Comment: @KRyan The link question does not cover Greater Two-Weapon fighting, as well as seems to imply that the attack from ITWF is from the mainhand weapon which seems wrong RAW. Removed mention of TWF from this question.

Comment: The answer's the same for Greater and Perfect as it is for Improved. I'm not seeing anything in that answer suggesting the extra attack is from the main hand. To be perfectly clear, "iterative" in the TWF-only case there is referred to as "iterative main" in the ITWF case; the difference between the two is the attack labeled "iterative offhand".